# Anagram code using C++ only works sometimes

Tags: c++

My code returns 0 when I compare strings such as Pizza and Pizza or aaa and aaa. When I ran the the code through a debugger, it showed that during my second for loop, it was actually adding elements to arr1 from the first for loop. How should I go about fixing this issue?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int anagram(string s1,string s2){
  int array1[26]={0},array2[26]={0};
  //if string lengths are different
  if(s1.length()!=s2.length())
     return 0; //they are not anagrams
 //for string1
  for(int i=0;s1[i]!='\0';i++){
  //storing frequency for each letter in the string   
   array1[s1[i]-'a']++;     
  }

 //for string2
  for(int i=0;s2[i]!='\0';i++){
    //storing frequency for each letter in the string     
       array2[s2[i]-'a']++;   
  }
   //comparison step
    for(int i=0;i<26;i++){
    // if any letter has different no of occurence, 
   // then strings are not anagrams
    if(array1[i]!=array2[i]) 
       return 0;
   }

   return 1;// else they are anagrams
}
```

Comment: Debugger.  Time to use a Debugger.  When you used a debugger, which statement is causing the issue?  What were the values in the variables?  What were the expected values of the variables?

Comment: If your function is Boolean (e.g. returns `true` or `false`), it should be of `bool` type and return `true` or `false`; not 1 or 0.  BTW, the returning of 1 & 0 is archaic (like decades old).  Use the modern `bool` type.

Comment: Pass your `string` by reference or `const` reference if you are not going to change them.  This prevents the compiler from wasting execution time and making copies of the strings before passing them to your function.

Comment: The `std::string` type *does not require a terminating `'\0'` character*.  Your first loop may not end.

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` and `using namespace std;` is a bad combination. To be honest you don't want to use either of them, but including pretty much the entire Standard Library with a non-standard header that might vanish at any time and then pulling pretty much the entire Standard Library into the global namespace leaves you to deal with tens of thousands of identifiers that can now conflict with your code in strange and rarely wonderful ways isn't a top-notch coding strategy.

Comment: You don't convert your strings to all lower case.  Upper case letters in your string may invoke *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Also a side note is that this code is not portable, since the code assumes that characters `a` through `z` are contiguous in the collating sequence used.  Believe it or not, there are EBCDIC machines where doing that subtraction of `a` will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array is of size 26. This means it can hold 26 items. However, you're passing strings with *52* unique characters in them. Remember, **capital and lowercase letters have different ASCII values!**

So `'P' - 'a'` may not be in the bounds of your array, and hence will be undefined behavior.

You need to make sure to convert the characters to lowercase first, ie:

```
array1[tolower(s1[i])-'a']++;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is good for lowercase characters only
Solution: Convert each character to lowercase before counting.